# Applying ABS function to values of a range within Rank formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to achieve the following in Excel, if possible. I have a range of positive and negative numbers, such as:

[image: Range]

I would like to get the rankings of these numbers based on the criteria which one is closest to 0 in absolute terms, by using a cell formula. So, for the set of numbers above, the output should look like this:

[image: Output]

Ideally, I would be able to achieve this using the RANK function of the following format:

```
=RANK(ABS(A1),ABS(A1:A5))
```

However, it appears that I cannot refer to the range A1:A5 as above. If there is a way to get an output which would correspond to what I am trying to achieve above, I would just multiply it by -1 and add the length of the range to it.

Does anyone know if and if yes, how, I can make the formula above work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RANK() must use Ranges not arrays and `ABS(A1:A5)` would return an array, but we can work around that by using SUM in an array formula:

```
=SUM(--(ABS(A1)>=ABS($A$1:$A$5)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This will sum the number of entries less than or equal to the absolute of the number.

[image]